# Analysis of this analog mux circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, multiplexer

I would love an analysis of this circuit, as I suspect the mux is trying to digitally adjust the gain of the amplifier. But what is it adjusting, current gain or voltage gain? And how?

[image: mux circuit]

Comment: Looks like a trans-impedance amplifier with programmable gain, where is the circuit from?

Comment: @sstobbe  Looks like a duplicate of an [earlier question by the same Hero](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/439450/will-love-to-understand-how-the-circuit-works-based-on-this-schematics) too.  That one has got a 20W driver connected to the working electrode.  Must be a big electrochemical cell.

Comment: @Nick good catch on duplicate. Yes you must be correct on the application with the use of 'working' net is in reference to an electrochemical sensor/cell.

Comment: @sstobbe the circuit is from a potentiostat. Studying it for a class and its really difficult

Comment: @Nick please can you briefly explain that 20W (also how you knew its 20W?) driver connected to the WE in the other circuit I posted. just its principle

Comment: How did I know about 20W?  I read datasheets.

Answer (score 1):

As sstobbe says, as shown it's a transimpedance amplifier with gain from 10nA/V to 10mA/V in 1-3-10 steps. Maybe for something like a photodiode.

The amplifier is a fA Ib type, and the switch typically has pA leakage at room temperature.

It appears to have a +1.5V reference bias on the input.

There's a good chance it's unstable at higher gains.

Comment: its actually unstable at higher gains, but how could you tell it will be unstable at higher gains?

Comment: @Hero The input capacitance (including the op-amp, whatever you have connected to it, and any cables in between) and the feedback resistor give you another pole which reduces the phase margin.

Comment: If the source cable capacitance and resistance is 6us =Tau this would balance the loss in phase margin so it is like a probe balance with the same RC feedback time constant. Not unstable.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany - even worse the common terminal of many analog multiplexers have a terribly large capacitance to ground. The MAX4617 shown has 32pF to ground. This invites instability without a large compensating capacitor across the feedback resistor. The high-gain feedback resistors don't have any.

Comment: @KevinWhite Yes, exactly, I should have included the MUX capacitance too.

Comment: Excuse me, but is it nA/V or V/nA?

Comment: @user287001 Vout/Iin  is V/nA. iIn/Vout is nA/V.

Comment: I know that, but beginners can automatically consider Gain=output/input. Unit nA/V can cause something for them.

Answer (score -1):

It's an 8 port MUX with 3 binary addresses and 5 decades of V gain control with caps to compensate for a source & cable shunt impedance, with an RC time constant of 6 us.

[image]

it’s not ideal for a 17MHZ GBW decade gain design.  But it is ideal OP Amp for a 20fA input bias current.  a better attenuators would shunt Voltage feedback with lower impedances and a  high series R, but any design using a single stage is pushing the limitations for 7 decades.  The source to feedback capacitance ratio must be considered in gain/phase response as the switches shunt 32pF on output to inverting input.

Comment: can you please briefly explain the working principle from the working electrode to the ADC

Comment: @Hero  So this is for an academic class.  What have you figured out yourself so far?  What have you read?

Comment: Input RC to switch to inverting input with negative feedback Rf\Rin gain control to ADC via selectable 1 of 8 switches with series R on 7 of them and 0 Ohms on one

Comment: Another -1 silent critic

Comment: @Nick its for a class project. asked to understand the circuit the working principle of this circuit (Potentiostat circuit). trying to understand branch by branch. read up on the types of amplifiers, multiplexers, switches etc, but all I see online are just explanations to calculations and formulars. Nothing related to how you guys are being able to decipher all you have from one look at the circuit. what books can I read to attain this level of knowledge please?

Comment: Start with this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier#Negative-feedback_applications  there are lots of application manuals for Op Amps and CMOS switches are useful for switching but have a resistance that must be considered. Many IC options exist with lower resistance. Archive.org has all the old National Semi handbooks on Op Amp designs.  WIth high gain bandwidth, it's all about feedback resistance  to input ratios (or impedance ratios) . where gain and bandwidth is a fixed product in each Op Amp.

Comment: Thank you @sunnyskyguy. Any other tips especially with c programming for electronics design

Comment: Your education is all about learning how to learn . With search tools  this is only limited by your imagination with the right key words.

Comment: Thank you so much Sir

Comment: please I would love to know why a precision matched resistor divider is used in a circuit. the out of a DAC and an amplifier are fed as input to a precision matched resistor divider (max 5491) why?. I sit acting as a comparator or combining both inputs

Comment: am new to circuit design and I want to ask a really silly question. most times I see comparators are used between two points (input voltage vs the reference voltage). Why the need for the comparator when you can just link both ends with a wire and they will still have the same potential across them. please no snide comments or insults please...…...lol